# Trying to load in more then 50 sounds using soundPool.load

Tags: android

I have a sound board with about 80 sounds. After it loads 53 sounds, there is like a minute delay, then it works fine.  Is there a way to fix this?? 
The sounds are loaded by
 soundPool.load(this, cGlobals.mSounds[i], 1);. 
I tried it on both a acer tablet (3.0 )and a Virgin smart phone (2.2) 
The smart phone delay is not as long, about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the 53th sound is very large and thus takes long to load? Remember that it completely converts them to wave sounds when loading. Possible async, so the method returns fast (don't know that for sure).

Also the memory could be full? 80 sounds is a lot, especially uncompressed. I doubt the soundpool is designed for that amount of sounds.